# How to do user segmentation in machine learning when with all categorical features

Tags: machine-learning

I have a problem where all my feature columns are categorical. Now how can i find out user segmentation. Shall i do just smart binning and use kmodes algorithm ? Is there any other way and suggestions

Answer (score -1):

Let's assume **A** be a matrix of size **M X N** where **M** is the number of users and **N** is the number of features for each user.Each value in this matrix is categorical(0 or 1).
For user segmentation, it would be great to have an embedding in a **K** dimensional space where K can be chosen based on experimentation.
To get the embedding, we could try matrix decomposition of **A** where,

A ~ transpose(V)*V

V is the embedding of size **M X K**. The product of V and its transpose would approximate A. This embedding will be a representation of the user in a K dimensional space. You can use this embedding on any clustering algorithm and check which works the best.
For the value of K, choose the best algorithm and try experimenting with different values of K on this algorithm.

I hope I have answered your question. Let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: Can i use  Multiple correspondence analysis MCA to do same thing  and then use kmeans ?

Comment: I haven't used MCA before but when I looked at the content, it is related to segmentation in general. https://personal.utdallas.edu/~herve/Abdi-MCA2007-pretty.pdf will give you a better idea about this.
After MCA, you can apply k-means and get user segmentation